# Join two tables statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables as shown below:

Table1:

| Entity | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 10 |

Table2:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1/1/2023 |
| 2/1/2023 |
| 3/1/2023 |
| 4/1/2023 |
| 5/1/2023 |

The final result expected:

| Entity | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1/1/2023 |
| A | 6 | 2/1/2023 |
| A | 7 | 3/1/2023 |
| A | 8 | 4/1/2023 |
| A | 9 | 5/1/2023 |
| B | 10 | 1/1/2023 |
| B | 11 | 2/1/2023 |
| B | 12 | 3/1/2023 |
| B | 13 | 4/1/2023 |
| B | 14 | 5/1/2023 |

A usual left join can join the **date** column from table2 to table1 but how do I increment the **value** column based on 'row numbers' from the date column?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Probably using the `row_number()` function.

Comment: It looks like you need a cross join and a window function - what problem do you have with your current query?

Comment: I was just using a simple query like this but quite certain is not correct. Select entity, value, table2.date from table1 left join table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *cross join* will give you the cartesian product of your two tables (ie match each row in `t1` to every row in `t2`), *row_number* will provide your new values:

```
select t1.Entity, t2.Date, 
  t1.Value - 1 + Row_Number() over(partition by entity order by date) as Value
from t1
cross join t2
order by Value;
```

Comment: The performance of Row_number() in this scenario is really bad. :(

Comment: The performance of a cartesian join is never going to be great, the performance of row_number can depend on various factors eg suitable indexes for the partitioned and ordered columns. Looking at the execution plan and tuning indexes to eliminate sort operators can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can first use [cross join](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp) operator to get dates applied all entity, and then use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to set the current value for each row.

See the following code as example:

```
SELECT
  entity,
  dt,
  value+COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY entity order by dt)-1 as value
FROM
table_1
CROSS JOIN
table_2
ORDER BY entity,dt
```

[RUNNING EXAMPLE SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e266c9/2)

example output:

| entity | dt | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 5 |
| A | 2023-02-01 | 6 |
| A | 2023-03-01 | 7 |
| A | 2023-04-01 | 8 |
| A | 2023-05-01 | 9 |
| B | 2023-01-01 | 10 |
| B | 2023-02-01 | 11 |
| B | 2023-03-01 | 12 |
| B | 2023-04-01 | 13 |
| B | 2023-05-01 | 14 |